# Are there any 802.11ac usb 3.0 adapters working well in Ubuntu?

Tags: usb, wifi, wireless, network-adapter

Is there any WiFi USB adapter that works without any errors with the 802.11ac WiFi standard in the 2.4GHz and the 5GHz bands with USB 3.0?

I have a WiFi adapter (TP-Link Archer T4U), but it gives me a lot of problems (One being that TP-Link does not provide a driver for Linux...). There are problems when I try to change/read the power transmission, when I try to get the bit rate, etc.

So, I was wondering if there was a WiFi adapter that works with the 802.11ac standard and USB 3.0 that does not have so many problems and will work well.

Comment: Do you have a budget for this adapter?

Comment: Well, not in principle.
What I want to know if there are USB 3.0 dongles that work well with the standard 802.11ac and if anyone has had any experience with.